# Is an integrand unique?

Tags: integration

Suppose $x,y \in [0,1]$ and suppose
$$
\int_0^x f(x,y) dy = 5x - \frac{3x^2}{2} 
$$

Can I conclude that $f(x,y) = 5 - 3y$? Is that the only possible solution?

Comment: This might help, how do u define a integral?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: I define a Riemann integral as the limit of Riemann sums.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been given a homework for a few years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's another:
$$
\int_0^x \left[ 5 - \tfrac{3}{2} x \right]\,dy
= \left[ 5y - \tfrac{3}{2}xy \right]_0^x
= 5x - \frac{3}{2}x^2.
$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Also note that this gives infinitely many examples given by the affine span of such functions.  My gut says that is all the examples, but haven't been able to confirm it yet.

Comment: Its so obvious and I didn't see it. Thank you! I guess its impossible to pin it down.

Answer (score 2):

Any solution $g(x,y)$ of the equation
$$ \int_0^x g(x,y)\; dy = 0$$
can be added to one solution of your equation to get another.  For any positive integer $j$ and any function $h(x)$, $g(x,y) = (j+1) h(x) y^j - j x h(x) y^{j-1}$ works.  So there are lots of solutions.